# Express router-level middleware

Tags: javascript, express

I believe in express 4.0 this is the way for creating router-level middleware, is this a good approach creating multiple instance of `express.Router`?

```
var userRouter = express.Router();
var paymentRouter = express.Router();

userRouter.get("/login", function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("okay this is route")
});

paymentRouter.get("/pay", function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("okay this is route")
});


app.use("/user" ,userRouter);
app.use("/payment" ,paymentRouter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate routers can be used to modularize your application.

In your case, it looks like you have (at least) two distinct parts of an API or web app, a user part and a payment part:

```
app.use("/user",    userRouter);
app.use("/payment", paymentRouter);
```

It's perfectly reasonable to use two separate routers for this.

Usually, each router is modularized even further by placing them in separate modules, that contain the specifics for that router:

```
app.use("/user",    require('./routers/user'));
app.use("/payment", require('./routers/payment'));
```

So you get a nice [separation of concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

The Express documentation also touches on this topic [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router).

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on what you want to achieve.

The normal way is to have just one router that is used to define your routes.

Please explain better why you would like to have more routers.